# Javascript Converting human time to timestamp

Tags: javascript, date

Using javascript, How can I convert a "human time" string like "Wed Jun 20 19:20:44 +0000 2012" into a timestamp value like "1338821992"?

Comment: Can you elaborate some more what do you want to do? how do you get this string?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just create a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object from it and do [`.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) or use [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

```
var d = new Date("Wed Jun 20 19:20:44 +0000 2012");
d.getTime(); //returns 1340220044000

//OR

Date.parse("Wed Jun 20 19:20:44 +0000 2012"); //returns 1340220044000
```

Works great if your "human time" string is in a format that the Date constructor understands (which the example you posted is).

---

**EDIT**

Realized you may mean a Unix timestamp, which is seconds passed since the epoch (not ms like JS timestamps). In that case simply divide the JS timestamp by `1000`:

```
//if you want to truncate ms instead of rounding just use Math.floor()
Math.round(Date.parse("Wed Jun 20 19:20:44 +0000 2012") / 1000); //returns 1340220044
```

Comment: `NaN` on both counts. This is because of locale, and is exactly why parsing human strings is such a problem.

Answer (score 5):

In theory, with `Date.parse()`. In practice, however, with the thousands of different ways to express date and time (the least of which being the names of days/months in different languages), it's far easier to get the date in its component parts instead of trying to read a string.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the date/time you've provided is in seconds not milliseconds. So you'll need to divide by 1000 to get the date/time in seconds.

```
//Gets date in seconds 
var d1 = Date.parse('Wed Jun 20 19:20:44 +0000 2012')/1000;
alert(d1);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AUt9K/

Answer (score 1):

Simply add following:
`new Date().getTime()`

This should get you timestamp of current time.
Example:
`var url = "http://abc.xyz.com/my-script.js?v=" + new Date().getTime();`