# How to compare Iphone system Device Date with PersianDate?

Tags: php, jquery, json, datetime

I am beginner.
I would like to compare iPhone device Date with my Persian Date Logic.
So, my Date() Function not working on Iphone.
I would like to this normal Date() function fetch iPhone current system date/time. Any function to get iPhone Device Date()?
My code is below.
Thanks for helping me in advance.

```
function _compareDate(dateString) {
    var selectedDate = new Date(dateString);
    console.log(selectedDate);
    var now = new Date();
    if (selectedDate < now) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Now Date Returns: `Fri Feb 03 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: why is this set with php, jquery and json tags?

Comment: Sir, I developed web page in PHP and performing on iPhone.

Comment: Ok but this is just a javascript question and javascript is not tagged :P

Comment: Can you show the date formats, to see if we can help you? :)

Comment: Yes, I added, I just need to check both dates are gregorian. I just wanna to compare both.

Comment: explained there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172568/javascript-converting-human-time-to-timestamp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Converting human time to timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172568/javascript-converting-human-time-to-timestamp)